# RegEx How to I check the length of the string whilst also using match groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to solve a password checker challenge and I've got to a stage where 1 string is matching for two expressions.

Rules:

- return 'too short' for any string that is less than 6 characters
- return 'okay' if the string is less than 12 characters, features one or more underscores, or a number, or with a mix of uppercase/lowercase letters

  ```
  var str = 'aBB33'

  var lessthansixRegex = new RegExp(/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])|(?=.*?\d{1}){0,6}$/);

  var okayRegex = new RegExp(/(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])|(?=.*?\d{1})|(?=.*?[_]{1})/);

  if (okayRegex.test(str) && str.length < 12) {
      return 'okay';
  } else if (tooshortRegex.test(str) && str.length < 6) {
      return 'too short';
  }
  ```

Is there a way to check this or are the paramaters of the challenge messed up.

One solution you might easily spot is the lack of '*' however the 'okay' regex must have that parameter as an or '|' because there are other strings than need to match it that also don't include '*'.

Feel free to let me know if you spot any other bugs.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well I'm just getting used to RegEx so I thought it might be good practice to try and use RegEx to check for the string length. Weirdly though, if I only use the string.length property, the 'okay' regex is still matching.

Comment: Hmmm... the look ahead does seem to pass the tests, more so than the classic ^(pattern)$ (I tried a few methods before arriving to this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've overcomplicated things here, why not just check the string lengths rather than write a regex for it? Also I think your regex could be simpler:

```
var str = 'aBB33';

var okayRegex = /[_\d]|[A-Z]+.*[a-z]+|[a-z]+.*[A-Z]+/;

if (str.length < 6 || str.length > 11) {
  return 'password must be between 6 & 11 characters';
} else if (okayRegex.test(str)) {
    return 'ok';
} else {
  return 'invalid password';
}
```

Seeing as this is about the regex let me explain what's happening:

```
[_\d]          // match any underscore or digit (number)
|              // or (checks whether what's before or after is true)
[A-Z]+.*[a-z]+ // check for at least one A-Z followed by any gap
               // of characters followed by at least one a-z
|              // or
[a-z]+.*[A-Z]+ // reverse of last check (lower then upper)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm just getting used to RegEx so I thought it would be useful to try to solve the challenge using as much of it as I can. I definitely wouldn't use it in production code. Also the string needs to validate a few things, not just length.    Thanks for the explanation and in particular you version for the Uppercase / Lowercase pattern - I've been struggling with that, and your pattern seem easy to remember. 

Comment: Thanks again I managed to solve all of the test cases using a mix of your solution and the one below. Thanks for inspiring a different way of thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex seems too complicated. You can reach your solution by testing against each individual regex and provide a specific error message based on each condition by doing something like this

```
var containsNumber = new RegExp('\d');
var containsUnderscore = new RegExp('[_]');
var containsUpperCase = new RegExp('[A-Z]');
var containslowerCase = new RegExp('[a-z]');       

  if (str.length < 6 || str.length > 11) {
  return 'password must be between 6 & 11 characters';
} else if (!containsNumber.test(str)) {
    return 'password must contain a number';
}else if (!containsUnderscore.test(str)) {
    return 'password must contain underscore';
}else if (!containsUpperCase.test(str)) {
    return 'password must contain upper case character';
}else if (!containslowerCase.test(str)) {
    return 'password must contain lower case character';
}
```

Comment: Interesting... your pattern treats the problem as an alert to the user. The challenge is actually pitting the solution as a visual cue, so you'd show if a pattern matches. Thanks for chipping in though, it was very useful to see another way to treat the pattern and I'm defiantly going to try to cut down the patterns into smaller chunks. 

Comment: Thanks again I managed to solve all of the test cases using a mix of your solution and the one above. Thanks for inspiring a different way of thinking about the problem.